# Firebase Analytics - logging screen_view not working in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, analytics, firebase-analytics

I have recently started looking into Firebase/Google Analytics. I am trying to use the following piece of code to log a `screen_view` event, but nothing happens in my console. I am using SwiftUI and the following code is run in an `.onAppear` clause.

```
Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView,
                   parameters: [AnalyticsParameterScreenName: "Initial Load",
                                AnalyticsParameterScreenClass: InitialLoadView.self])
```

Is there something that I have misunderstood or is there a bug with SwiftUI and Firebase Analytics at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has added better SwiftUI support. For iOS 13.0+, there is now a View Modifier that can be used on the views that you'd like to support:

```
    /// Logs `screen_view` events in Google Analytics for Firebase when this view appears on screen.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - name: Current screen name logged with the `screen_view` event.
    ///   - class: Current screen class or struct logged with the `screen_view` event.
    ///   - extraParameters: Any additional parameters to be logged. These extra parameters must
    ///       follow the same rules as described in the `Analytics.logEvent(_:parameters:)` docs.
    /// - Returns: A view with a custom `ViewModifier` used to log `screen_view` events when this
    ///    view appears on screen.
    public func analyticsScreen(
        name: String, 
        class: String = "View", 
        extraParameters: [String : Any] = [:]
    ) -> some View
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
          Text("One")
        }
        NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
          Text("Two")
        }
      }
      .navigationTitle("sample")
      .onAppear() {
        Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView,
                           parameters: [AnalyticsParameterScreenName: "\(ContentView.self)",
                                        AnalyticsParameterScreenClass: "\(ContentView.self)"])
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

Comment: `onAppear` will rerun on any state changes. I wonder if there's a better place to log the navigation event, so it only logs once.

Comment: @nelu what did you end up using to defeat that problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can log a manual screen_view just like you would any other event in Google Analytics. You can also include the two optional parameters (i) screen_name and (ii) screen_class, as well as any custom event parameters you want to include. The two optional parameters take the place of the firebase_screen and firebase_screen_class event parameters that get passed into automatically collected screen_view events.

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)

```
// After enough time has passed to make this screen view significant.
Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView, parameters: [
    AnalyticsParameterScreenName: screenName!,
    AnalyticsParameterScreenClass: screenClass!,
    MyAppAnalyticsParameterFitnessCategory: category!
])
}
```

Please follow the link below for details:
[Manually tracking screen views in Google Analytics](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/08/google-analytics-manual-screen-view.html)